# How to show the count of reviews

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-listing, list.phtml

How to show the count of product review on the category page?
Now i just can get the stars, but no counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code i solved my problem.

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short')
?>
```